# position relative top/bottom ignored internet explorer 6/7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning

Code:

```
    <div class="container_16" id="enlacesSeo">
        <div id="titulo_destinos">
            <h2>PRINCIPALES DESTINOS</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="destinos">
            <ul class="enlacesSeo">             
                <li>Items</li>
                                <li>Items</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS:

```
*Enlaces principales destinos - SEO */
#enlacesSeo {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    height:50px;
    position:relative; top:-15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;



}
* html .enlacesSeo {
    /*hack IE6*/
     position: relative;
     bottom: 30px;
}

*+html #enlacesSeo {
    bottom: 30px;
}

#enlacesSeo div#titulo_destinos{
    float:left;
    width:179px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
```

Firefox, chrome and Opera OK; Internet Explorer 6/7, ignored :(

Even tried:

```
* html .enlacesSeo {
    /*hack IE6*/
     position: relative;
     bottom: 30px;
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Take a look to the pictures

[image: Firefox View]
[image: IE view: the div its not top:-15px or bottom:30px :?]

Comment: Please post your entire HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you have `position: relative` and both `top` and `bottom`, the `top` wins, so if you want to set the `bottom` value, you need to set `top: auto` first.

So, in your case it would be

```
* html #enlacesSeo {
    /*hack IE6*/
     top: auto;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 30px;
}

*+html #enlacesSeo {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`#enlacesSeo` refers to an ID, not to a class. `.enlacesSeo` would target the class.

`* html .enlacesSeo` would never target anything because there is no parent element for `<html>`.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: I was explaining to @Tomalak what `* html` does.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks, did not know that. Chances are I will instantly forget, though. ;-)

Comment: aha, ok! i got it working with margin-top:-15px; do you think its a OK solution??